# Existence of an invariant distribution and explosions in continuous time Markov chains

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider an irreducible continuous time Markov chain defined on a countable state space with an infinitesimal generator Q.

Assume the generator has an invariant distribution $\pi Q=\pi$,  and assume for every i,  $\pi_i>0$  and $\sum_i \pi_i =1$.

Can this chain be explosive?

Comment: Yes:  But, what is the context of this question?  You need an additional _regularity_ assumption that says there are a finite number of transitions in finite time.  It would be sufficient to say that the sum of the transition rates out of any state is uniformly bounded by a finite constant.

Comment: A counter-example is a birth-death chain with $q_{i,i+1} = 2(4)^i$ and $q_{i,i-1} = 4^i$. The embedded chain goes to $\infty$ with prob 1, but there is such a $\pi$ vector.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for the general case where there is no uniform bound on the transition rates.

Comment: For your example I doubt that there is $\pi$ which has a finite sum. I will work it out and come back to you

Comment: You can just solve the detail equations.

Comment: Ok, how to rule out explosiveness in general? Thnx

Comment: I never saw a counter-example before, I just made it up but it is likely a standard example.  The intuition is that we actually traverse the entire state space in finite time, so the $\pi_i$ probabilities could still be physically meaningful as (roughly) expected fractions of time in state $i$ over the finite simulation.   See chapter 3, Appendix 3A.4 in this book for a formal statement of the steady state theorem for CTMC, under the regularity condition I mentioned :http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/datanets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This summarizes my comments above: The condition given in the question is *almost* sufficient for a steady state to exist.  You also need a *regularity condition* that says there are only a finite number of transitions in finite time.  For the regularity condition, it is enough to have a (finite) uniform bound on the sum transition rates out of any state.

For a counter-example that does not satisfy the regularity condition:  Consider an irreducible birth-death chain with state space $S = \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ and transition rates: 
\begin{align}
q_{i,i+1} &= 2(4^i) \quad \forall i \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} \\
q_{i,i-1} &= 4^i \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2 , 3, ...\} 
\end{align}
You can show there are positive probabilities $\pi_i$ that satisfy the detail equations $\pi_i q_{i,i+1} = \pi_{i+1}q_{i+1,i}$ for all $i\in S$.  However, the embedded discrete time chain is a random walk that is more likely to step forward than backward, and so the embedded chain $\rightarrow \infty$ with prob 1.  Intuitively, we can understand it this way: the continuous time chain traverses the entire infinite state space in finite time, and so the $\pi_i$ probabilities can (roughly) be viewed as expected fractions of time being in state $i$ over the finite simulation.

A link to a formal statement of the steady state theorem for CTMCs (including the regularity conditions) is given in the above link.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a theorem that establishes that the stationary distribution when exists can always be interpreted as expected fractions of time being in state i over the finite simulation (even in the case of explosive chains)?

Comment: I do not know.  I gave that as intuition, so I suppose I am really making that a conjecture. There are some references to works by Ross in the Bertsekas and Gallager book (Appendix 3A.4), and that likely has more info.  I have never seen this material covered in books or papers, since most either treat discrete time Markov chains, or treat continuous time chains but immediately assume the regularity condition.

Comment: consider a queue with $q_{i,i-1}=i, q_{i,i+1}=2$. Then the stationary distribution is a Poisson with mean 2. There is no uniform bound on the rates. How to show that no explosion occurs?

Comment: This looks like an $M/M/\infty$ queue.  Even though there is no uniform bound on the rates, it can be shown that it makes  a finite number of transitions in finite time.  Suppose the queue starts at some initial condition $Q(0)$.  Let $transitions(t)$ be the number of transitions during $[0,t]$, being the number of arrivals plus the number of departures.  Let $A(t)$ be the number of arrivals and $D(t)$ be the number of departures, with $D(t) \leq Q(0)+A(t)$.  Then $$transitions(t) = A(t) + D(t) \leq 2A(t) + Q(0)$$ But $A(t)$ is Poisson and is finite with prob 1.